# NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: []("title"))

Tags: json, flutter

I get this error after fetching data from a json;

my model is like this:

```
class JobModel {
 final String title;
 final int id;
 final String slug;
 final String content;

JobModel(this.title, this.id, this.slug, this.content);

JobModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
  : title = json['title'],
    id = json['id'],
    slug = json['slug'],
    content = json['content'];
```

}

and this is my function to fetch data from the json file:

```
List<JobModel> jobList;
Map<String, dynamic> jsonResponse;
Future<List<JobModel>> _getJobs() async {
var response = await http.get(
    "https://www.eradauti.ro/api/context?pathname=/anunturi/pagina-1&userID=");
this.setState(() {
  jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
});
jobList = List<JobModel>();
jsonResponse.forEach((key, value) {
  JobModel job = JobModel.fromJson(value);
  jobList.add(job);
});
print(jsonResponse[0]['title']); //shows null
return jobList;
```

}

my json file looks like this:

```
{
  "context": [
    // first JobModel Map
    {
      "title": "some title here",
      "id": 1234,
      "slug": "some slug value",
      "content": "the rest of the object content",
    },
    // second JobModel Map
    {
      "title": "some other title here",
      "id": 5678,
      "slug": "some other slug value",
      "content": "blah blah,",
    },
  ]
}
```

Can you tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response format is different from what you have coded to.

The structure is this:

```
{
"context": {
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 15,
            "title": "Auto-Moto",
            "slug": "auto-moto",
            "content": "Vanzari-cumparari de automobile, piese acte. Anunţurile sunt destinate zonei Radauti-Suceava<br />",
            "related": {
                "link": "/anunturi/auto-moto-15",
                "archiveLink": "/arhiva-anunturi/c/auto-moto-15",
                "deletedPostCount": 387,
                "postCount": 22
            }
        },
```

So, to get to the jobs list, you should parse it accordingly. The correct statement to get to the jobs list should be this:

```
print(jsonResponse['context']['categories'])
```

To be able to create the list of job models, try this:

```
var json = jsonResponse['context']['categories'];
var jobList = List<JobModel>();
json.forEach((key, value) {
  print(key);
  JobModel job = JobModel.fromJson(value);
  jobList.add(job);
});
print(jobList);
```

Try this snippet:

```
Future<List<JobModel>> _getJobs() async {
     var response = await http.get(
    "https://www.eradauti.ro/api/context?pathname=/anunturi/pagina-1&userID=");
     jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
     var json = jsonResponse['context']['categories'];
     var jobList = List<JobModel>();
     json.forEach((key, value) {
       print(key);
       JobModel job = JobModel.fromJson(value);
       jobList.add(job);
     });
     print(jobList);
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to know where should I pus `var json = jsonResponse['context']['categories']` if I put it before `jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body)` nothing happens, no errors and if I put if after I get the error `Local variable 'json' can't be referenced before it is declared.`. But `print(jsonResponse['context']['categories']);` worked.